# Why would System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer be undefined in a SSRS 2005 report?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm trying to serialize a data structure and pass it to another report via parameter, and this line of code:

```
Dim s As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(System.Collections.HashTable))
```

Produces this error:

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
The definition of the report '/myReport' is invalid.
There is an error on line 22 of custom code: [BC30002] Type 'System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer' is not defined.
```

How can I get around this?  I have been able to use fully defined .NET classes in other lines of code, including the following:

```
Dim outStream As New System.IO.StringWriter()
```

and

```
Private colorMapping As New System.Collections.Hashtable()
```

Any ideas why this would fail?  This is SQL Server Reporting Services 2005.

Comment: I'm not familiar with reporting services, but I'm guessing you need to add a reference to 'System.Xml' to your project

Comment: Of course!  Thanks - if you create that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can close the question out:

You'll need to add a reference to 'System.Xml' to the project.